# Reshape error on Matlab I can't figure out?

Tags: matlab, reshape

Trying to add a row and column of zeroes to a user inputted matrices, can't fin any way past the reshape error

```
n = input ('Please Enter Desired Number of Rows:');
disp ('');                                               % User prompted to enter the desied rows for the matrices.
m = input ('Please Enter Desired Number of Columns:');
disp ('');                                               % User prompted to enter the desired columns for the matrices.

for x = 1:n
    for y = 1:m
        p (x,y) = input ('Enter Matrice Values:');
    end
end

p = reshape (p, n, m);

% Adding Row of Zeros
a = zeros (1,m+1)
% Adding Column of Zeros
b= zeros (n,1)

Output_Matrix = [p b; a]
```

Comment: You never initialized `p` in your code. What does it contain before the loop? You should probably initialize it to the right size before entering that loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `reshape`, get the size of `p` that was input by the user using `[m, n] = size(p)` and create `Output_Matrix` that's one row and one column bigger. Set the first `m` rows and `n` columns to `p`. Finally don't forget to preallocate any arrays before accessing them.

```
% User prompted to enter the desied rows for the matrices.
m = input('Please Enter Desired Number of Rows: ');    disp ('') 

% User prompted to enter the desired columns for the matrices.
n = input('Please Enter Desired Number of Columns: '); disp ('')                                               

p = zeros(m,n);
for x = 1:m
    for y = 1:n
        p(x,y) = input('Enter Matrice Values: ');
    end
end

[m, n] = size(p);
Output_Matrix = zeros(m+1,n+1);
Output_Matrix(1:end-1,1:end-1) = p;
```

```
Output_Matrix =

     1     2     3     0
     4     5     6     0
     7     8     9     0
     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: You can initialize the matrix `p` to `zeros(m+1,n+1)`, then you won't need that copy at the end.

Comment: Sure, but I fear that `p` might be coming from another function that we have no control over before being created.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a p matrix from some previous code and you want to expand it, you can simply do this to get that extra row and column of 0's appended:

```
% p is pre-existing from some other code
p(end+1,end+1) = 0; % this appends extra row and column of 0's
```

But if you are building the p from scratch and know the desired size ahead of time, then Chris's comment about pre-allocating p to zeros(m+1,n+1) is probably the way to go.